# No service after installing cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, 4.4-kitkat

After I installed CyanogenMod, I noticed I couldn't call anyone, receive calls, or text, and it says I'm roaming. In the status part of settings, it says my phone number is 000-000-xxxx (x's are numbers) but the imei is still the same. I can't find anything online about this problem, please help!

Comment: Neither can we, joe – but maybe a few more details can help: what device are you talking about? Which image did you install (and where from)? Was it exactly matching your device? Is it a "nightly build", or rather a stable one?

Comment: Did you read the changelog and bugs for the ROM from the developers website (the forum you got it from)?

Comment: So did you read the developers website on your ROM? You don't state in your edit.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got a solution to "No Service" after installing Cyanogenmod 7 on HTC Incredible 2. The answer is simple and it does not have anything to do with flashing radios, reinstalling ROMs, etc.

Simply turn the phone off and remove the battery to take out your SIM card. Then switch it back on without the SIM in it. After it has finished rebooting, 
make sure the network bars are appearing even without any signal (in other words, an "x" on the bars) and also airplane mode is off. Now go to "Mobile Network Settings" and choose "CDMA/GSM (auto)" and not the preferred one.

Now turn off the phone and put the SIM back in. Replace the battery, start the phone, and *tadaaa!* Your phone will have the most amazing connection!